# find() method in python3

Tags: python-3.x, find

I'm unable to understand what's the second argument in the find method in python3 is for.I searched it online but couldn't get a satisfactory explanation.For ex, please explain the use of the number 5 ,20 in the following code.

```
>>> str = "this is a string"
>>> str.find("is", 5)
5
>>> str.find("is", 20)
-1
```

Comment: When I google python find, this is the top hit. Are you saying that doesn't explain it well enough? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm

Comment: "is" starts at offset 5 in the string. You're searching for "is" starting at offset 5 and it finds it and returns its offset from the beginning of the string.  The 2nd line says search for "is" starting at offset 20 in str.   But since there it can't find "is" after offset 20, it returns -1 (failure). In this case not only is it unable to find an is after offset 20, the string isn't even 20 characters long.

Comment: @clearlight i viewed it earlier, the doubt i had was in that example(in the link you posted) once there was no second argument , in next case it was 10 but in the both cases the output is 15 .I was unable to get that

Comment: It's the way they wrote function. If the 2nd argument is omitted it means start searching at offset 0. They assume you always want it to return the offset of the substring from the beginning of the main string, but that you may want to start searching from different positions.

Comment: Oh,thanks i get it!! @clearlight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the starting index of where `find()` will begin searching.

`str.find("is", 5)` will search starting at the cursor index 5 (the equivalent of searching the substring `str[5:]` (which is `"is a string"`)

Similarly, `str.find("is", 6)` will search starting at the cursor index 6 (the equivalent of searching the substring `str[6:]` (which is `"s a string"`). This will return -1 because after the cursor position 6, the string `"is"` is not in the search string

**Edit: This is a useful concept to remember, but doesn't apply to Python since Python doesn't have a char type.** 
Remember, a string is similar to an array of single characters, so the string `'hello'` is similar to `str = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`, and we can choose exactly which position in this array we want to start searching from with the 2nd argument in `find()`

Answer (score 1):

`5` inside the  brackets is the index from which begins  the research of the substring,  the `5` in the output  is the index in which the substring was found.

See [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm)  tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In the find() function in python3 the second argument you are talking about is the starting index which is by default 0 but you can reset it to any value by giving this second argument.
The find function returns the index of the subtring if found, else it gives -1